# Python, stripping the characters off a tuple

Tags: python, tuples, strip

First post!
I am doing a basic python program, this stuff is very advanced for me :D, and I want to strip off the characters `' , ()` from a tuple when it is printed. What I have, that prints the list out without stripping, is:

```
    view = map(str, listplanets)
    print("\n".join(view))
```

"listplanets" is the name for the tuple, though you guys probably know this XD. I tried `view = map(str, listplanets).strip("\"',")` and I have tried moving this strip command to every place I could think of. I always get an error saying that the map does not have the attribute strip. If I convert the tuple into a string like so `view(str(listplanets))` it will print out each character on a separate line rather than each tuple item. This is the output that I get:

```
('Mercury', 0.378)
('Venus', 0.907)
('Mars', 0.377)
('Io', 0.1835)
('Europa', 0.1335)
('Ganymede', 0.1448)
('Callisto', 0.1264)
```

It would be greatly appreciated if someone can answer this for me :).

Comment: what output u want?

Comment: Well, I want to remove the brackets, quotation marks and commas.

Comment: @friendywill Can you share a more complete code with the variables str and listplanets defined?

Comment: The title of your post is very misleading.

Comment: You can do something like `view = map(lambda x:x.strip('\",'), listplanets)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lines = ['{} {}'.format(planet, n) for planet, n in listplanets]
print('\n'.join(lines))
```